# How to get the original value of an attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

is there a way to get the original value that an ActiveRecord attribute (=the value that was loaded from the database)?

I want something like this in an observer

```
before_save object
  do_something_with object.original_name
end
```

The task is to remove the object from a hash table (in fact, move it to another key in the table) upon updating.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

#### Before rails 5.1

Appending `_was` to your attribute will give you the previous value.

#### For rails 5.1+

**Copied from Lucas Andrade's answer below**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50973808/9359123

---

Appending `_was` is deprecated in rails 5.1, now you should append `_before_last_save`

Something like:

```
before_save object
  do_something_with object.name_before_last_save
end
```

Will return the name value before your last save at database (works for save and create)

The difference between `_was` and `_before_last_save` according to the documentation:

**_was** source [from docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty/attribute_was)

```
def attribute_was(attr)
  attribute_changed?(attr) ? changed_attributes[attr] : __send__(attr)
end
```

**_before_last_save** source [from docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html)

```
def attribute_before_last_save(attr_name)
  mutations_before_last_save.original_value(attr_name)
end
```

Comment: E.g.: for `self.context`: `self.context_was`

Comment: Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: the documentation can be found at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/attribute_was

Comment: In the documentation, there is no "deprecation" warning for `_was`.

Comment: poor lucas his answer got stolen, current SO is sort by the most upvotes, so instead copying we could start upvotes lucas's

Answer (score 19):

#### For rails 5.1+

Appending `_was` is deprecated in rails 5.1, now you should append `_before_last_save`

Something like:

```
before_save object
  do_something_with object.name_before_last_save
end
```

Will return the name value before your last save at database (works for save and create)

The difference between `_was` and `_before_last_save` according to the documentation:

**_was** source [from docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty/attribute_was)

```
def attribute_was(attr)
  attribute_changed?(attr) ? changed_attributes[attr] : __send__(attr)
end
```

**_before_last_save** source [from docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html)

```
def attribute_before_last_save(attr_name)
  mutations_before_last_save.original_value(attr_name)
end
```

You can see a better example [here](https://blog.toshima.ru/2017/04/06/saved-change-to-attribute.html)

Comment: `attribute_was` has been deprecated in favor of `attribute_in_database`, whereas `attribute_before_last_save` is a completely new method as of 5.1 that has no equivalent in earlier versions of Rails. Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25337#issuecomment-225166796

Answer (score 8):

ActiveRecord's [`attributes_before_type_cast`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002349) method returns a hash of attributes before typecasting and deserialization have occurred.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look in rails documentation

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Model.attribute_was return previous value :D

Comment: _was also still in Rails 5.2.x