# Prevent Rails from storing temporary invalid values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2.

It is normal that when we submit a form, after validation, it would still keep the invalid value in the field, and render to the view to show what has been entered.

Say I have Paperclip which let users to upload avatar. When I upload a non-image file, such as `abc.pdf`, it would return invalid, but this invalid value will still be stored temporarily in the `avatar_file_name` column.

Because of this, when I render the page with errors, my view will try to return an image tag and look for `abc.pdf` because it is in the `avatar_file_name` field.

How can I prevent Rails from storing this temporary invalid value?

Comment: seems to be more of a paperclip issue than a rails one

Comment: I think it's a general behaviour that the invalid values are stored temporary. I am looking at the `.changes` method in Rails Dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PaperClip, but you should be able to set the avatar_file_name to nil in the controller if you spot an error, something like this

params[:user][:avatar] = nil

Comment: What if I want to store the previous value instead of `nil`?

Comment: @Victor, then you should put up some logic for not to render the file if it wasn't validated or something like that

Comment: @ted, can shed some light?

Comment: You mean the previously correct image rather than the wrong pdf?

Comment: @BasharAbdullah, that's right. But trying to `@user.update_attributes(params[:user][:avatar] = nil)` would need me to declare `attr_accessible` of those columns, which I am reluctant to.

Comment: @Victor, for paperclip `after_save :validate_avatar; def validate_avatar if(good_name_format_etc?) do something; end`

Comment: @ted, but it's not even saved (since it doesn't pass validation). I check my database, the value is not saved. But when the page is rendered (with errors), the invalid values are in it.

Comment: @Victor, `but this invalid value will still be stored temporarily in the 'avatar_file_name' column`?

Comment: @Victor no I didn't mean that. I meant set the passed params[:user][:avatar] to nil so that there will be nothing to render in the page view, not update_attribute. There is a _was value that gets the old original field value. You can set avatar value to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487548/how-to-get-the-original-value-of-an-attribute-in-rails

Comment: @BasharAbdullah, it would not set if I just pass that line.