# Save Model with a partially failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Lets say I have the following model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :wheels,
                :engine_cylinders

validates :wheels, :engine_cylinders, presence: true, numericality: true

end
```

Lets say I then have the following controller action:

```
@car = Car.find(params[:id])
@car.wheels = "foo"
@car.engine_cylinders = 4
@car.save
```

This save will fail as wheels will fail the numericality condition.

Is there any way to persist the succesful attributes (in this case engine_cylinders), while adding the invalid attributes to the errors array? E.g. is there a "soft" validation in Rails?

Comment: This really should be clarified (e.g. definition of "propogate"). Also, note that validations communicate with the `save` mechanism by populating the `errors` array, so any validation which adds something to that array is going to prohibit any subsequent save.

Comment: Though 'propagate to disk' is a common idea, "persist" is probably the more standard verbiage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to write a **[Custom Validator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)**.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :wheel_range,
           :engine_cylinder_range

  def engine_cylinder_range
    flash[:notice] = "engine_cylinder was not saved because it wasn't a number" unless engine_cylinder.is_a? Fixnum
    # set engine_cylinder back to old value
  end

  def wheel_range
    flash[:notice] = "wheels was not saved because it wasn't a number" unless wheels.is_a? Fixnum
    # set wheels back to old value
  end
end
```

You don't have to use `flash` here, you could use any variable for internal processing or re-display.

You may also want to put this custom validation check on the [`:before_save` hook](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).  Use the [`_was` magic method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1487605/263858) to get the old value.

Comment: Custom validation methods should not raise, but do `errors.add(:attr, ...)`.  And most definitely they should not raise anything inheriting from `Exception`.  Descendants of `StandardError` are app level errors and others inheriting from `Exception` are about environment.  Also plain `rescue` without type won't catch the latter.

Comment: @TeroTilus I thought that adding errors would thus prevent the save, which OP wants to ensure occurs in all cases.  So `errors.add` and then `self.save` ?  Clearly we want this validation-handling to occur in the validator, else we will litter the code with `log 'zzz' unless something.valid?;  something.save(validate: false)`   which is just messy

Comment: It does prevent the save. So most definitely does raising an error. He should do `@car.valid?` when he wants to check the validity and `@car.save(:validate => false)` when he wants to save bypassing validations, as @pdobb already pointed out.

Comment: @TeroTilus Read the question again: OP wants to propagate attributes the are valid, and alert/warn/notify of the others *without saving them*

Comment: Do you read "propagate" to mean "save", because I interpreted it as "notify somebody".  If you do, that together with your non-raising answer makes sense.

Comment: The user might not be happy if the software decides to throw away her carefully edited values after deciding they are "invalid". :)  And this still left me wondering what would be the expected behavior if the old value also was invalid (maybe newly created car)?

Comment: It's also not clear what "set xxx back to old value" means. Where is the "old value" coming from and where is it going?

Comment: For what it's worth, I read "propogate" as "save". I thought the OP wanted to write the valid attributes to the database and not write the  invalid attributes. Of course, that's got its own problems.

Comment: Obviously, if the record is new, the old values are `nil`.  there is actually a convention to do this in Rails, using a `:before_save` hook - but I don't have time to do everyones' research for them ;)

Comment: @AbrahamP meh, I lied it seems... it's just too-easy to lookup these things.  Answer modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to bypass validations you can always do so with:

```
if @car.save
  # ...
else
  @car.save(validate: false)
end
```

You may want to have a different conditional on that or whatever... but this is how you bypass validations on a one-off basis.

This may, however, destroy the errors array so you could rebuild it after the `save(validate: false)` with:

```
@car.valid?
```

You can also bypass validations one-at-a-time using `@car.update_attribute(:attribute, <value>)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if the model is valid or not without saving it `@car.valid?` does exactly that.  It also adds invalid attributes to errors array.  And @pdobb already pointed out how to bypass validation when saving.